# Angular2 File upload for Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, angular

I know how to do amazon s3 file upload in angular 1. May i know how to upload file in angular 2.  but i didn't find any solution for angular 2.

Comment: Could you add hint about the way you did in Angular1? This way, I will be able to adapt your code to Angular2...

Comment: I have used this method to upload file into amazon bucket in angularjs http://www.cheynewallace.com/uploading-to-s3-with-angularjs/

Comment: @Deepakrao have you had The chance To check out my answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It still needs better/some security.

#### html

```
<form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" action="">
<input type="file" (change)="fileEvent($event)" />
</form>
<button (click)="uploadfile(f)">Upload file!</button>
```

#### ts

```
export class Page2 {
    myfile:any;
    file:any;

constructor() {
}


   uploadfile(event) {
        AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'YOUR-ACCESS-KEY';
        AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'YOU-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY';
        var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'YOUR-BUCKET-NAME'}});
        var params = {Key: this.file.name, Body: this.file};
        bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
            console.log(err, data);
        });
    }


    fileEvent(fileInput: any){
        var files = event.target.files;
        var file = files[0];
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where did this class `AWS` came from?

Comment: It's the  AWS js sdk @CassioLandim

Comment: Unsupported body payload object .. i get this error when i try to upload .. any help?

Comment: How did you import the sdk to access an `AWS` variable

Comment: is it safe to put the secret on the client side js like that ?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use a separate GET request that retrieves the secret access key when the user authenticates themselves, instead of storing it there?

Comment: @CESCO I used your code but when I added this line  var files = event.target.files; its showing error message that is :- Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. I used anjular2

Comment: I had the same issue. Try using fileInput instead. Should get rid of the EventTarget error

     fileEvent(fileInput: any){
           var files = fileInput.srcElement.files;
           var file = files[0];
           this.file = file;
       }

Comment: see this answer on how to install AWS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834304/importing-aws-sdk-in-angular-2-application

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a Rails backend (or even Node) the easiest solution is to create a presigned url (which must be a PUT) and then use an Angular service to call that PUT and attach the file in the body of the request.

You can read more about how I did that [here](https://medium.com/@richardmcsharry/angular2-railsapi-presigned-url-for-s3-uploading-ead609b85eee).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this problem already but all you have to do is rebuild the post request you send to S3

You can check out this:
https://github.com/ntheg0d/angular2_aws_s3

Comment: thanks. i have converted this [link](http://www.cheynewallace.com/uploading-to-s3-with-angularjs/) into angular2 now its working fine. thanks for your support

Comment: Can you post your Angular 2 code?  I'm having trouble

Comment: @JeremyThomas check the GitHub link I posted above, the code might be outdated tho

Comment: @JeremyThomas see my answer for a link to how I solved this, lots of Angular code shown.