# Importing AWS SDK in Angular 2 Application

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, angular2-services

I am attempting to use the AWS SDK in my Angular 2 application and am getting quite stuck. Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Installed the aws sdk into my Angular 2 application using `npm install aws-sdk`
2. Installed the types using `npm install --save-dev @types/node`
3. Attempted to include the AWS modules several different ways in my Angular 2 service: `declare var AWS: any;`, `import AWS = require('aws-sdk');`, and finally `import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';`.

when I attempt to use the first and third type of import, I don't get a transpiler error until I attempt to access a library within the AWS object, i.e. `AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2` gives me the error `';' expected.`. And when I attempt to use the second method, I get the error:

> Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015
>   modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from
>   "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.)

Am I missing a step? I've looked at the github project https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular2-quickstart/blob/master/src/app/service/aws.service.ts but their project doesn't explain how they imported the SDK.

Answer (score 14):

You need to:

```
npm install aws-sdk -S
```

Then make sure you have this type installed (if you are not sure, then just run the code below):

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Now in your src folder, you will find `tsconfig.app.ts` (make sure not to get confused with `tsconfig.ts` at the root).

types line is empty and looks like this prior to editing: `"types": []`. You need to edit it.
The tsconfig.app.ts should look like this after you add `"types": ["node"]`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
  "module": "es2015",
  "baseUrl": "",
  "types": ["node"]
},
"exclude": [
  "test.ts",
  "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Now you can just

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

Comment: Worked for me after restarting "ng serve". Thanks!

Comment: The application failed to start in IE 11 after I guess, adding, the "types": ["node"]

Comment: I was getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined` error which I fixed by adding `<script>var global = global || window;</script>` I guess we need to add this because aws-sdk was written with nodejs in mind so we need to define `global` variable.

Comment: Thanks @Rash, adding that line to `index.html` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working with AWS with angular as my frontend, and am using the same angular cognito quickstart project for my authentication and authorisation flow.

For installation, I used `npm install aws-sdk --save`

The aws-sdk is under dependencies' in my **package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
    .......
    "aws-sdk": "^2.41.0",
    .......
}
```

If you are using angular cli, make sure you include the aws-sdk into your **angular-cli.json**

After these I used `declare var AWS: any;` And I am able to use the library without any problem.

Comment: So this almost works, but I found that I still have to include `<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.50.0.min.js"></script>` index.html. Am I missing something? I feel like I shouldn't have to put this in the index.

Comment: You shouldn't need to include the script in the index.html.
Make sure you re-run the project via `npm run` or `ng serve` after you include the sdk  in your **angular-cli.json**