# Angular 5: IE not working after removing "types": [ ] or changing to "types": ["node"] in tsconfig.app.json during installing of aws-sdk

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, aws-sdk

I followed the steps in this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44857822/6105852  to  upload file to s3 bucket using aws sdk, however, after making the changes in types in tsconfig.app.json, the angular application would not work in IE. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer in [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834304/importing-aws-sdk-in-angular-2-application/44857822#44857822) is applied to Angular 2 application, instead of Angular 5.

Based on your description, I create an Angular 5 application, and install the AWS SDK using the following command:

```
npm install aws-sdk -s 
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

After installing the AWS SDK, and uncomment the following code in the polyfills.ts file, the application works well on IE/Chrome browser.

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

Then, you could use the following code to use the AWS SDK in a JavaScript file:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

More details about using AWS SDK, please refer to [AWS SDK Usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/#Usage_with_TypeScript) and [Angular 5 Gallery App using AWS S3](https://codeburst.io/angular-5-gallery-app-using-aws-s3-heroku-part-2-server-side-development-deployment-c30dd1d4d098)